# In CSS, how to scale multiple overlayed images responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have multiple images overlayed on top of a background, here's an example:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="images/background.png" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"/> 
    <img src="images/overlay1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; "/>
    <img src="images/overlay2.png" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px; "/>
</div>
```

The above snippet works if the browser is in full screen mode. If I reduce the browser size, only the background.png is scaled accordingly, but overlay1.png and overlay2.png both remained the same size fixed at their positions. I tried changing the all position attributes to `relative` but the overlay images are appearing in the wrong spots.

How would I refactor this to allow all images within a div tag to scale properly relative to each other? BTW, I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 as the default CSS theme.

More info. All images are of fixed size, e.g. the background is 640x480, shown at position 0, 0. The overlay images are also fixed size and need to go into certain positions in relation to the background image. e.g. an overlay maybe 64x64 and goes to position 15, 24 (top, left), another maybe 128x128 and goes into position 200, 231, etc. With these precise position overlaying, the background + the overlays becomes a complete picture.

Comment: It's because of `position:absolute`, which looks like is necessary.  There is an alternative though - use multiple background images on the `div` instead of in the markup.

Comment: Is setting the bottom/right positions an option?  Or are these images of unknown sizes?

Comment: Example using background image: http://jsfiddle.net/tuuJP/1/

Comment: Chris, seems like the background image becomes the foreground image, while the rest appear below it. I need to have the first image as the background image, and overlay the rest on top of the first one. Also, the 2nd and 3rd images seems to be scaled to the size of the first one.

Comment: cimmanon, I updated the question. All images are of fixed size, the overlays need to go into certain positions. Just like layering in Photoshop.

Comment: @azgolfer how you stack them in your CSS changes the order they appear (front to back).  They aren't scaled to the size of the first, they are scaled to the size of the viewport.

Comment: Just read your new info.  This is where I'm at now: http://jsfiddle.net/UhuJe/1/; however, there are issues: 1) If the screen gets too narrow, the 128px image falls off the background (which would present itself on a landscape oriented device) 2) (kind-of the same as #1) it only responds to width, so changing the height of viewport won't effect the smaller images.  It's hard to know for sure without your specific requirements, but to get it fairly foolproof, you may need to implement some light JavaScript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to keep everything in scale when resizing the browser window you should use percentage values for both the size and position of the overlays.

In your case everything is fixed so it's just a matter of converting the pixels to percentages, for this you need the simple formula:

```
% value = px value / container px value * 100
```

For example, for Overlay 1 size:(64x64) position:(24,15):

```
width = 64/640*100 = 10%
top = 15/480*100 = 3.125%
left = 24/640*100 = 3.75%
```

Now just set the overlays to be absolutely position and apply the correct values for each property:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.container img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay1{
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.125%;
    left:3.75%;
}

.overlay2{
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.666%;
    left: 36.09%;
}
```

Check out the **[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wA9e/1/)**

Comment: Weird, your demo works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and IE10. The background just stay fixed without scaling down in Firefox and IE10.

Comment: @azgolfer you're right, I updated my answer, it seems not all browsers supported the inline-block trick